# NoSuchMethod in dart?

Tags: dart, dart-pub

**Getting warning while trying to use noSuchMethod().**

> The method missing isn't defined for the class Person.

But according to the docs and other examples, whenever we call a non-existing member then, noSuchMethod() should be called. Whose default behavior is to throw noSuchMethodError.

```
 void main() {
    var person = new Person();
    print(person.missing("20", "Shubham")); // is a missing method!
 }

 class Person {

    @override
    noSuchMethod(Invocation msg) => "got ${msg.memberName} "
                      "with arguments ${msg.positionalArguments}";

 }
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**According to the official docs for invoking an unimplemented method, you have to satisfy one of the following points:**

- The receiver has the static type dynamic.
- The receiver has a static type that defines the unimplemented method
  (abstract is OK), and the dynamic type of the receiver has an
  implemention of noSuchMethod() that’s different from the one in class
  Object.

***Example 1 : Satifies Point First***

```
class Person {
  @override  //overring noSuchMethod
    noSuchMethod(Invocation invocation) => 'Got the ${invocation.memberName} with arguments ${invocation.positionalArguments}';
}

main(List<String> args) {
  dynamic person = new Person(); // person is declared dynamic hence staifies the first point
  print(person.missing('20','shubham'));  //We are calling an unimplemented method called 'missing'
}
```

***Example 2 : Satifies Point Second***

```
class Person {
  missing(int age,String name);

  @override //overriding noSuchMethod
    noSuchMethod(Invocation invocation) => 'Got the ${invocation.memberName} with arguments ${invocation.positionalArguments}';
}

main(List<String> args) {
  dynamic person = new Person(); //person could be var, Person or dynamic
  print(person.missing(20,'shubham')); //calling abstract method
}
```

Comment: Thank you. As a non-native English speaker, I can't understand the explanation of the official doc here...